# Why does DSolve return HeavisideTheta[0] which is not defined at zero?

Tags: differential-equations

Why does Mathematica return solution of an ODE with `HeavisideTheta[0]` in it, when this is not even defined at zero?

The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta.html) says

[image]

```
ClearAll[y, t];
ode = y''[t] + 2*y'[t] + 10*y[t] == DiracDelta[t]
ic = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}
DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[t], t]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it could have just returned the simpler answer

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I could not simplify the result of Mathematica to remove `HeavisideTheta[0]`.

The question is: Why does it need `HeavisideTheta[0]` in the solution when this is not defined and where would this have come from?

I am using V 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

**Update**

About comments below. I know answer is correct, but my question what is the point of adding `HeavisideTheta[0]`? What purpose does it do?

```
ClearAll[y, t];
ode = y''[t] + 2*y'[t] + 10*y[t] == DiracDelta[t]
ic = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, y, t]
Assuming[t > 0, Simplify[ode /. sol]]
(*{ True} *)
```

Same thing will happen without `HeavisideTheta[0]`

```
mysol = y -> Function[{t}, 1/3 E^-t Sin[3 t]*HeavisideTheta[t]]
Assuming[t > 0, Simplify[ode /. mysol]]
(* True *)
```

**Update 2**

When solving this "by hand" one gets `1/3 E^-t Sin[3 t]` or for `t>0` this is the same as `1/3 E^-t Sin[3 t]* HeavisideTheta[t]`

```
ClearAll[y, t];
ode = y''[t] + 2*y'[t] + 10*y[t] == DiracDelta[t]
ic = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}
lhs = LaplaceTransform[ode[[1]], t, s] /. {y[0] -> 0, y'[0] -> 0}
rhs = LaplaceTransform[ode[[2]], t, s];
Y = Solve[lhs == rhs, LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s]];
InverseLaplaceTransform[Y, s, t] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, in all these, we have to assume `t>0` for solution to be valid and verified.

**Update 3**

Answering comment: **As I understand it, the problem is incorrectly stated:**

I was trying to answer this question from the textbook and this is how it was stated

[image]

Page 315 "DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS with Boundary-Value Problems" 8th edition by DENNIS G. ZILL, WARREN S. WRIGHT.

Comment: The result is correct. You can substitute whatever value you want for `HeavisideTheta[0]` and the solution would still be correct. Like, say, `HeavisideTheta[0]->1/2` or `HeavisideTheta[0]->0` or whatever...

Comment: I believe your simpler answer is correct for t>0, but not for t<0.

Comment: The purpose of `HeavisideTheta[0]` is explainerd here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Zero_argument. In some branch of mathematics you need certain value of Heaviside theta at `x=0`, sometimes you do not care what value it is at `x=0`.

Comment: "Note, in all these, we have to assume `t>0` for solution to be valid and verified." Why do you think so? The solution is valid for `t<=0` too.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I was saying that when I used LaplaceTransform to solve it. Using LaplaceTransform assumes time is positive. That is all. I agree with you, Mathematica's solution verifies for t<0 and also t>0.

Comment: `HeavisideTheta[0]` is an invention of Mathematjca developers, not a math notion. `HeavisideTheta` is an  attempt to implement the antiderivative of the $\delta$-distribution in Mathematica. Distributions are not usual functions and their values at points (especially belonging to the supports) make no sense. See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) ) for details.

Comment: As I understand it, the problem is incorrectly stated: `ic` are given at the support of `DiracDelta`. The incorrect formulation implies an incorrect answer. I think the returned input would be the right answer.

Comment: The command `DSolve[ode, y[t], t]` correctly answers [the weak solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution)  `{{y[t] -> 
   E^-t C[2] Cos[3 t] + E^-t C[1] Sin[3 t] + 
    1/3 E^-t HeavisideTheta[t] Sin[3 t]}}`

Comment: @nasser: The quote says nothing about the existence of the solution of the second IVP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `HeavisideTheta[0]` term is necessary to guarantee that the initial conditions are satisfied for the full solution.  If we drop the $\Theta(0)$ term from the solution and then take the derivative, we find that $\dot{y}(0)$ is not necessarily zero but *also* depends on $\Theta(0)$:

```
soln = DSolve[{ode, ic}, y, t]
othersoln = FullSimplify[soln /. HeavisideTheta[0] -> 0]
y'[t] /. First[othersoln]

(* E^-t Cos[3 t] HeavisideTheta[t] + 1/3 E^-t DiracDelta[t] Sin[3 t] - 1/3 E^-t HeavisideTheta[t] Sin[3 t] *)

y'[0] /. First[othersoln]

(* HeavisideTheta[0] *)
```

Conversely, having $\Theta(0)$ explicitly in the solution means that we are guaranteed to have $\dot{y}(0) = 0$, no matter what value we assume $\Theta(0)$ has:

```
y'[t] /. First[soln]

(* -E^-t Cos[3 t] (HeavisideTheta[0] - HeavisideTheta[t]) + 1/3 E^-t DiracDelta[t] Sin[3 t] + 1/3 E^-t (HeavisideTheta[0] - HeavisideTheta[t]) Sin[3 t] *)

y'[0] /. First[soln]

(* 0 *)
```

It is, of course, consistent to set $\Theta(0) = 0$ throughout;  but Mathematica returns the "agnostic" version of the solution that works no matter what value you assume for $\Theta(0)$.

Comment: As I understand it, the problem is incorrectly stated: `ic` are given at the support of `DiracDelta`. The incorrect formulation implies an incorrect answer. I think the returned input would be the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Its not correct, to give start values in the point of a singular distribution as inhomogenity.

What, if the start values are set a picosecond after the delta hammer?

The equation should describe a solution of an oscillator at rest for t<0 giving it a kick, so that the velocity
$$y'(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t y''(s) ds=\int_{-\infty}^t \delta(s) ds= H(t)$$
in the linear approximation for small t>0

```
 f[t_] = DSolveValue[{y''[t] + 2*y'[t] + 10*y[t] ==
                 DiracDelta[t],
                  y[-1]==0,y[-1]==0},y[t],t]
 ic = {y[-1] == 0, y'[-1] == 0}
```

$$\frac{1}{3} e^{-t} \theta (t) \sin (3 t)$$

This correct solution on $$-1<t<\infty$$ for the momentum transfer experiment to an damped oscillator at rest.

Comment: As I understand it, the problem is incorrectly stated: `ic` are given at the support of `DiracDelta`. The incorrect formulation implies an incorrect answer. I think the returned input would be the right answer.